# Did method "getPort" exist in jdk 1.7

Tags: eclipse, web-services, soap, xml-parsing, soap-client

I try to learn SOAP, by using WebService from Eclipse.
After I prased the WSDL, I have this problem with  generated classes.
"The method getHelloWorldImplPort() is undefined for the type HelloWorldImplService"

Did  method "getPort" exist in jdk 1.7  ? If not, what is the solution ?

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        try {
            HelloWorldImplService helloWorldService = new HelloWorldImplService();  
            HelloWorld helloWorld = helloWorldService.getHelloWorldImplPort();
            out.print(helloWorld.helloWorld("Silviu"));
        } catch (Exception e) {

            out.print(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you´re seeing doesn´t tell anything about `getPort`. It tells you that there is no method `getHelloWorldImplPort()` in your class `HelloWorldImplService`.

Comment: getPort () is a generated method  inside of HelloWorldImplService, after parsing WSDL,but in my project was not generated, because some issues in my code.